# Динамическое добавление элементов в WPF и работа с ними

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

В общем, я с БД получаю список пользователей (Заранее не известно сколько пользователей), модель:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Получив список пользователей мне нужно динамический вывести их в окно программы в таком вот виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, при сохранении я должен знать id отмеченных "птичкой" пользователей, чтобы продолжить работу с ними. Как мне динамический выводить данные в таком вот виде и как определять где есть "птичка", а где ее нет?

Модель при сохранении:

```
public class SaveModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection<YouClass>` в классе завести все эти поля, включая bool для чекера. Забиндить коллекцию на ваш ListView и прописать DataTemplate со своим дизайном элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего сделать Listbox, который будет содержать шаблон отображения.

```
<ListBox x:Name="_Users">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

А потом ему подсунуть List или какую-либо другую коллекцию как источник

```
_Users.ItemSource = UsersList;
```

Comment: Немного не так будет выравнено. Надо или у TextBox задать Width, или столбцы делать.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл ориентацию для StackPanel указать. Исправил.